# Present today's date as "Today" rather than "dd/mm/yyyy" in a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, date, jstl

Given a `java.util.Date`, what's the best way to display the date as `Today` rather than in some version of `dd/mm/yyyy` in a JSP?

Given a future date, I'd still like it to display in a `dd/mm/yyyy` format, but today should present as `Today`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper JSP/JSTL way would be using JSTL [`<fmt:formatDate>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html). You can use `<jsp:useBean>` to construct and put a `java.util.Date` in the page scope.

```html
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<jsp:useBean id="today" class="java.util.Date" />
<fmt:formatDate var="todayString" value="${today}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
...
<fmt:formatDate var="dateString" value="${bean.date}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
<p>The date is: ${todayString == dateString ? 'Today' : dateString}</p>
```

Note that I fixed `mm` to be `MM`. The `mm` stands for minutes, `MM` for months. See also [`SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 3):

This will do:

```
<%
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date currentDate  = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
Date myDate = someDate;
%>
<%=sdf.format(currentDate).equals(sdf.format(myDate))?"Today":sdf.format(myDate)%>
```

Comment: Not enough JSTL. OP tagged question with JSTL. *Scriptlets* are discouraged since a decade.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the date in question to the current date (given by creating a new Date() instance.  Does that help?

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
Date someDate = df.parse("10/13/2011");

if (someDate.equals(df.parse(new Date())))
  displayDate = "Today";
else
  displayDate = someDate.toString();
```

EDIT: the following changes would make this work:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
if (someDate.equals(df.parse(df.format(new Date()))))
```